# How can i get value of column in repeater in php like asp.net?

Tags: php

I am trying to do `repeater` in `php` like `asp.net`, where name is column of database table. How can I get value of column ?

```
$templte = "<h1>",{'name'},"</h1>";
_Repeater_val("select * from regi",$template);
```

Comment: Please post your attempts what you have tried GROW MORE

Answer (score 0):

PHP is very different from asp.net

PHP is much more technical, down to earth and manual than asp.net is

Essentially what you need to do needs to be broken down into 2 parts:

1. Get Data (in the form of rows or an array)
2. Loop through and output data

**Getting Data:**

There are a few ways of getting data from a database. A secure method that I recommend is the mysqli prepared statement (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

**Looping through and outputting data:**

Essentially what needs to happen is for each row/ item you get from the database needs its own spot on the page, so you will be generating this code by going through each row.

**One Possible Solution:**

This is using the prepared statement as mentioned before, and looping through the results to build the HTML code with the data we want.

```
<?php
$output = '';//the output we want
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");//database connection
$query = "";//your database query

/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    die();
}

/* Stage 2: bind result */
$curItem = NULL;//the database item we currently are on
if (!$stmt->bind_result($curItem)) {
    echo "Binding output parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    die();
}

/* stage 3: loop through all data*/
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output .= '<h1>'.$curItem'</h1>';
}
//output however you like
echo $output;//example output
?>
```